# Getting Plone running on dotcloud (not using uwsgi)

Tags: plone, wsgi, dotcloud

**Plan A - Plone via uwsgi**

I'm trying to deploy plone via wsgi on dotcloud.

So far I've installed the dotcloud tools and created a git repository that successfully deploys all the pieces to dotcloud. I use github to store all the relevant configuration. If you'd like to try it out these are the commands I'm currently using to deploy:

```
git clone github@github.com/pigeonflight/stack-python-plone
cd stack-python-plone
dotcloud create plone
dotcloud push
```

After deployment I was able to confirm (after "sshing" in to my dotcloud instance) that I am able to launch the stack using paster with the following command:

```
cd current
bin/paster serve production.ini
```

But when I try to visit the application at its url I get a uwsgi error, python application not found.

My wsgi.py file looks like this:

```
import os
from paste.deploy import loadapp
current_dir = os.getcwd()
application = loadapp('config:production.ini', relative_to=current_dir)
```

**Update**

Plan A is not working out for me. I initially started with the assumption that uwsgi was the only option for a Python app on dotcloud.

**Plan B - Plone on a port proxied by webserver**

I'm now open to Plan B which would use Plone as a worker running on a port and then make use of a proxy_pass to serve the site. As an added benefit, the "Plone on a port proxied by webserver" would be closer to the standard deployment approach for Plone in other scenarios.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answers from Ken Cochrane and jpetazzo were both helpful in guiding me to the solution. I decided to abandon wsgi for the moment. The solution required digging deeper into the dotcloud python service and accompanying nginx webserver. I found a way to pass directives to nginx that would configure a proxy_pass.

The resulting stack is now hosted at: https://github.com/pigeonflight/stack-python-plone

The key breakthrough came when I realized that I could pass commands to nginx by creating a **plone-uwsgi.conf** file, for my purposes I'm "hijacking" a file that was intended to pass addition wsgi configuration and using it for something different. The nginx server is configured to read *uwsgi.conf files after other key directives in the nginx.conf file (such as the location / {} directive. This provided an ideal way for me to override the (unneeded) wsgi code. In my case I use the file to "inject" a proxy_pass directive.

Here's how my **`plone-uwsgi.conf`** file looks:

```
  # This configuration file overrides the default file and allows you to run
  # your zope instance at the root of your dotcloud instance
  location ^~ / {
     rewrite ^(.*)$ /VirtualHostBase/http/$http_host:80/VirtualHostRoot$1 break;
     proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1:8080;
     include /home/dotcloud/current/proxy.conf;
  }
```

I also stored additional configuration in a file called proxy.conf which I included in the plone-uwsgi.conf file.

Here's my **`proxy.conf`** file:

```
client_max_body_size            0;
client_body_buffer_size    128k;
client_body_temp_path      /home/dotcloud/current/var/client_body_temp;

proxy_connect_timeout      90;
proxy_send_timeout         90;
proxy_read_timeout         90;
proxy_buffer_size          4k;
proxy_buffers              4 32k;
proxy_busy_buffers_size    64k;
proxy_temp_file_write_size 64k;
proxy_temp_path            /home/dotcloud/current/var/proxy_temp;
proxy_redirect                  off;
proxy_set_header                Host $host;
proxy_set_header                X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header                X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
```

In summary it should be possible to launch a new plone site in a dotcloud sandbox using the following commands:

```
instance=instancename
git clone git://github.com/pigeonflight/stack-python-plone.git $instance
cd $instance
dotcloud create $instance
```

Followed by:

```
dotcloud push
```

**Possible Issues:**
I don't know whether the precompiled packages that are downloaded by my custom script will continue to work if dotcloud makes changes to their worker instances.

Comment: Really nice, thanks for making this recipe available! I think that the pre-compiled packages should work, until we update the base images to e.g. Ubuntu LTS 12; but you should be safe for a while. (..."Famous Last Words" :-))

Comment: Is there any warning when the base images are updated? It would be great to be alerted (if not, I'd need to extend the system with a compatibility script that detects the base system and warns if it changes).

Answer (score 0):

A couple of questions/comments.

1. In your getplone.sh script you are creating a new virtualenv? why are you doing this? there is already a virtualenv created for you under ~/env (/home/dotcloud/env is full path).

   If you want to install stuff into it you can use ~/env/bin/pip, or even better you could just put your requirements in the `requirements.txt` file which I noticed you have empty right now.

   For more information about the code dependencies on dotCloud see this link: http://docs.dotcloud.com/0.9/services/python/#code-dependencies
2. If you want python 2.7 you should be setting that in your `dotcloud.yml`. See this link for more information. http://docs.dotcloud.com/0.9/services/python/#python-versions

   This is what your dotcloud.yml would look like after adding the python version.

**dotcloud.yml**

```
www:
    type: python
    postinstall: ./getplone.sh
    config:
        python_version: v2.7
db:
    type: postgresql
```

So in conclusion, I think the reason why it isn't working for you, is that wsgi is setup to use the ~/env virtualenv, and since you are creating your own virtualenv, and putting your code there, the uWSGI can't find your application. So if you change to using the default virtualenv, it should work as planned. Try out the changes I suggested, and see if they work for you.

Comment: Thanks Ken, this helps me to understand the dotcloud platform a bit more. I've now implemented a new variation of my configuration in a more "dotcloudish" way. It now uses python  v2.7 and I've added zc.buildout to the requirements.txt file. It builds beautifully and feels cleaner, it works if I log in and launch it with paster, but I'm still getting the same uwsgi error otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried to run Plone for a while. Last time I did (~1 year ago), it was possible to install it with "pip install Plone" but it took forever (because IIRC it went as far as compiling Zope and other stuff) and didn't work (because the egg-ification of the project wasn't 100% complete).

Assuming that things are still in that state, I would just use Plone default recipes (which, by then, used buildout), inside a `python-worker` service exposing a HTTP port. The key difference with a normal `python` service is that the `python-worker + HTTP` solution doesn't come with uwsgi, and therefore, lets you run `paster` or whatever is deployed by the Plone unified installer.

The end result will be closer to a standard Plone installation, which is very probably a good thing!

Comment: Based on what you're suggesting, I should explore a solution that runs Plone in a more standard way on a standalone port and uses nginx as a reverse proxy in front of it. I'm looking into the nginx.conf file information to see if this is the best route.

I still don't know how to launch the python worker, but I'll start digging more through the documentation in order to figure it out.

Comment: What if I wanted to launch a customized version of nginx with my own settings (not uwsgi) in the /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default configuration? I'd like to override the default location / directive which assumes uwsgi at the moment.